# Split Multiple csv files into sud-directories based on unique value they share

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, split

I have a slight problem and would like some help if possible.

I have 2 large csv files that share some unique values and I would like to split the records by the unique value in the fields `content` & `contentnum`. I would then like to create a sub-directory with the unique value as the folder name e.g `wax2` & `wax18` but with 2 new datasets saved as the same parent filename `large1.csv` & `large2.csv`. If the sub-directory already exists,, delete the old files and write new ones.

large1.csv

```
Content,Name,level,type
wax2,John,6,easy
wax2,Bob,12,hard
wax18,James,8,easy
wax18,Smith,16,hard
```

large2.csv

```
Contentnum,Color,level,type
wax2,Red,6,easy
wax2,Blue,12,hard
wax18,Blue,8,easy
wax18,Green,16,hard
```

So I would like to split two csv files above and have the results presented below with the folder name as the values so e.g `wax2/large1.csv` & `wax18/large2.csv`

Folder Name:Wax2
filename:large1.csv

```
Content,Name,level,type
wax2,John,6,easy
wax2,Bob,12,hard
```

Folder Name:Wax18
filename:large2.csv

```
Content,Name,level,type
wax18,James,8,easy
wax18,Smith,16,hard
```

Can someone help me do this in python please.Thank you.

I've got this far.

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far? SO isn't supposed to be a site where you can ask for someone to write you a program, but a Q/A site for specific programming related questions. Please have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas` to load the `csv` files as dataframes, then group them by `Content` and `Contentnum`, then loop the groups and save them to the directories:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

df1 = pd.read_csv('large1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('large2.csv')

df1_groups = df1.groupby('Content')
df2_groups = df2.groupby('Contentnum')

for name, group in df1_groups:
  if not os.path.exists(name):
    os.mkdir(name)
  group.to_csv(name + "/large1.csv")

for name, group in df2_groups:
  if not os.path.exists(name):
    os.mkdir(name)
  group.to_csv(name + "/large2.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!
The code snippet you supplied was very helpful. Is there a way I could incorporate a drop of 'content' & contentnum in the new split files

Comment: You can drop columns like this: `group = group.drop(['Content'], axis=1)` in the for loop.